# subset a dataframe based on values of a numeric vector

Tags: r

I have this data frame

```
A   B   C
1   h   t
2   d   q
3   w   t
4   o   f
5   t   b
```

And this numeric vector `v <- c(1,2,3)`.

I need to subset `df` based on the `v` elements... So in this example, `df` after subseting would be

```
A   B   C
4   o   f
5   t   b
```

Any suggestion? A for loop maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df[-v, ]
```

will return all rows excpet the ones in `v`.

Comment: Tx it worked with df, I tried it with another df (610 obs,48) and it did not work.. any possible reason?